# Region of uniform convergence is within or is equal to the region of convergence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Hey I have a short question about region of convergence and the region of uniform convergence.

Let $G$ be the region of convergence of a function $f\left(z\right)$. Note that $f\left(z\right)$ is described by some serie.

My question is, is it possible that the region of uniformly convergence of the function $f\left(z\right)$ is smaller (is within) the region of convergence of $f\left(z\right)$?

Comment: For an entire function that is not a polynomial, the Taylor series converges in the plane but uniformly only on (pre) compact sets (or if you want bounded sets) but the convergence is non uniform on the full plane say

Answer (score 0):

A complex power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k (z-p)^k$ must either converge only at $p$, converge pointwise on a disk $|z-p| < r$ and diverge when $|z-p| > r$, or converge for all $z$.  Pointwise convergence on the boundary must be decided on a case by case basis.

The proof is via comparison of the series of absolute values to a geometric series.  This argument also gives uniform convergence on any closed disk $|z-p| \leq r' < r$.  This argument can be found in any text on complex analysis.